# Migration & seed files to sql script

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp-3.0

I've created some migration and seed files using bake, but now the dba guys say i should use an sql script to create and populate the tables. Is there a fast way of converting the files, without having to write the script by hand?

Comment: DBA guys are probably wrong. :-) Using migrations will allow you to more easily keep the database up-to-date as you add new features. I've done projects both ways, and even when there's only one copy of the database that needs to be updated, I've found migrations by far the better option.

Comment: As a man who was with both sides of the barricades, I would say that DBA guys are completely right. Migration is a nice thing while you play with your personal workstation and database on it. But if you need to create several copies of database on dedicated server for testing or maintenance, migration will become a hell very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Connect to SQL Server with SQL Profiler and run your current migration. Written profiled script is the converted one. You need only set appropriate Profiler's filter properties.

Comment: I did something more or less similar. I ran migrations on local db and used create script option to export sql file with schema and data.